# Extracting rows with a specific column value using pandas, no headers on the columns

Tags: python, pandas

So, I run this code:

```
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, delim_whitespace=True, header=None)
```

My file is huge so I have isolated the first 14 rows and all 10 columns for clarity.

```
    X = df.iloc[0:14, 0:10].values
```

X when printed, comes out like this(as said in title, no column headers):

[image: 14 * 10]

So far, so good.

Now, I want to isolate the rows which have a 'CYT' string in the 9th column.
Assuming 0th index, I want to isolate rows 5, 9 and 12. Next, I want to put these three rows into a matrix for later use. How do I do that?

I am very new to python so I will welcome any guidance.

Thanks!
Shreeman

[EDIT]

Correct Code [THANKS PAVEL!]:

```
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.read_csv(fileName, delim_whitespace=True, header=None)
    X_CYT = df.loc[df.iloc[:, 9] == 'CYT']
    X_CYT = X_CYT.values  # This converts it to a numpy array
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't try to isolate those using indexing, use conditions instead:

```
X_CYT = X.loc[X.iloc[:, 9] == 'CYT']
X_CYT = X_CYT.values  # This converts it to a numpy array
```

Comment: Also, when I said 9th column, I started out at the 0th index. Your 10 should be 9, if you wanna change it. Thanks again!